# Redirect only once in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a footer where i am setting the cookie upon language selection. So when the user returns to the website again, then with the help of cookie i am redirecting the user to the page locale url.
I am checking the cookie value in componentDidMount() lifecycle hook. But when the user redirects it again reads the cookie and the redirection goes in an infinite loop. How can i make the redirection occur only once.
I am using es-cookie npm package for the cookie mechanism.

Here is my code written in the lifecycle hook.

**Update:**

If the URL consists of /en-us/aboutus. It returns the condition as true and redirects indefinitely.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { ariaLabels } = this.props;
    this.props.initializeApp(ariaLabels.currentLanguageName);
    var currentLanguagePath = getCookie('language_url');

    // Redirect if location doesn't match with cookie language_url
    let locale = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

      if(locale.endsWith(".html")) {
        locale = locale.slice(0,-5);
      }
      if(locale.endsWith("/")) {
        locale = locale.slice(0, -1);
      }

    if(locale !== currentLanguagePath && currentLanguagePath !== undefined) {
      window.location.href = "/" + currentLanguagePath;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before redirecting you should check that the current page isn't already using the expected language prefix, so for example

```js
// Assuming currentLanguagePath value looks like 'en-us'

if(!window.location.pathname.startsWith('/' + currentLanguagePath)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work if i add sublinks or trailing slashes in the URL. so for eg if i put localhost:3000/en-us/content/article, it still redirects.

Comment: When location is `localhost:3000/en-us/content/article`, `location.pathname` will be `/en-us/content/article` so you can test it starts with `/en-us`. I edited the answer to add the `/`

Comment: Here is the issue is even if it is /article in the end. The condition becomes true and redirects.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (getCookie("firstVisit") != "true") {
    document.cookie = "firstVisit=true";
    location.href="Your_New_URL";    
}


function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

I hope this will help you on restricting infinite redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `currentLanguageName` from props is same as `currentLanguageName` from cookie. If they same, you don't need to redirect, else - redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check to determine whether the user is already on the correct route:

```
if (
  currentLanguageName &&
  currentLanguagePath &&
  window.location.href != `/${currentLanguagePath}`
) {
  this.props.initializeApp(currentLanguageName);
  window.location.href = "/" + currentLanguagePath;
}
```